# Jump to source from console output in Visual Studio Code

Tags: console, rust, visual-studio-code, code-navigation

Is it possible to setup Visual Studio Code to jump to source from console output? Here is my output:

[image]

Is it possible to click on reduced.rs and open this file?

Comment: On linux I get a mouse-over hint on the filename telling me to "Ctrl + click to follow link" (which works)

Comment: I don't have it on Windows, most probably I'm missing some esoteric knowledge of vscode setup.

Comment: Could be the "Rust (rls)" extension I'm using.

Comment: I also have rls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a partial solution to the problem I'd propose using **Problems** panel:

[image]

If the rest of plugins are installed correctly, it will show you lines of code with error messages (unfortunately partrial):

[image]

But it allows to jump to the source code.